# What is the role of headroom in DPDK Mbuf？

Tags: dpdk

For a newly allocated mbuf, the area at which the data begins in the message buffer is RTE_PKTMBUF_HEADROOM bytes after the beginning of the buffer, which is cache aligned.
[image]

As far as I know, the headroom does not contain any data. So I wonder why there should be a headroom in the mbuf？In addition, the default size of HEADROOM is 128B.I've tried setting the HEADROOM size to something bigger, like 5120B, and it doesn't affect performance. So I want to know what is the purpose of the existence of the Headroom, and is there any theoretical limit to the size of the Headroom?

Comment: I am trying to change the headroom length in one of my projects by re-defining RTE_PKTMBUF_HEADROOM. However, my packets always use 128B of headroom. How did you change the headroom length to 5120B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DPDK mbuf's headroom is suited for prepending extra data (typically, *metadata*) to the *packet* data. Its use cases are PMD-specific. For example, [virtio](https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/drivers/net/virtio/virtio_rxtx.c#L1036) PMD stores `struct virtio_net_hdr` in it. Other drivers may use this for offload results: checksum validity status, packet classification, hash values, you name it.

As for the upper limit, it depends on the mbuf object's maximum size and on the minimum *packet data* room, which, in turn, might be PMD-specific. For the majority of use cases, it's OK to just rely on default size.